# A file include a file in another directory which have links, How to set relative path for links?

Tags: php, html, relative-path

my project directory as follows.

```
root 
  css
  img  
  src
    login 
       login.php
    dashboard
          basic
              header.php
              footer.php
              profile.php
              manage.php 
          department
              add_depart.php
    configuration
          config.php
```

Here the `header.php` included `profile.php`, `manage.php` , `add_depart.php` and `config.php`.

In the `header.php` have links point to the another files that are kept in `basic` folder. My problem is when i include the `header.php` in `add_depart.php` and `config.php` the links are not working. I know include only copy the file into `add_depart.php`. the links cant access within department folder.

How can i set relative path for the links inside the `header.php` can access the links provided by header from basic,department,and configuration folders.

I am also tried with `getcwd()` , `dirname(__FILE__)` .

Please Help.

**Header.php**

```
$path_r = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'];
$path_l = $path_r . '/root/src/dashboard/basic/';
 <li class="dropdown">
    <a href="#" data-target="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown"> Settings <b class="caret"></b></a>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
        <li><a href="<?php echo $path_l ?>/profile.php">Profile</a></li>
        <li><a href="<?php echo $path_l ?>/config.php">Config</a></li>
        <li class="divider"></li>
        <li><a href="logout.php">Logout</a></li>
    </ul>
</li>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're confusing the file system paths with the URL path.

`$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']` contains the absolute path to the document root on your server (the file system), not the URL. The same goes for `getcwd()` and `dirname()`.

Just start the URLs with a slash: `<a href="/path/to/profile.php"` etc, and the URL's will be the same no matter where you include it.